# How can I determine if an AMD CPU supports Integrated graphics on the chip?

Tags: cpu, amd-radeon, integrated-graphics

I want to buy an AMD CPU. But before I buy one, I want to know if it supports Integrated Graphics. What is a sure fire way to look up any AMD CPU and determine that it supports Integrated Graphics?

Meaning, I want to buy the CPU, but not purchase a stand alone graphics card as well. Many Intel CPU support integrated graphics. But I'm unsure of AMD cpus.

After a bit of research, I understand AMD calls their integrated graphics: APU (accelerated processing units).

If I look up any Intel CPU, I can quickly go to a specific Intel's page and check the Processor Graphics Category, and determine if supports video.

That isn't the case with AMD.

How can I determine if an AMD CPU supports Integrated graphics on the chip?

Answer (score 0):

You might be referring to APU, the AMD term for a CPU with integrated graphics,
which doesn't need an additional graphics card (or GPU) in order to function.

You will find information about these CPUs in:

- [Wikipedia : AMD Accelerated Processing Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Accelerated_Processing_Unit)
- [Wikipedia : List of AMD accelerated processing units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_accelerated_processing_units)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I determine if an AMD CPU supports Integrated graphics on the chip?

AMD lists every processor on their website.  If an AMD processor has an integrated GPU capability, on the specification page for the product, there will be a Graphics Specification section.

If this section does not appear for the product then the product does not have integrated graphics capabilities.  [Here](https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/processors) is a list of every AMD processor, you can easily sort and find, the products with a GPU core.

> After a bit of research, I understand AMD calls their integrated graphics: APU (accelerated processing units).

This isn't always the case.  AMD's [Ryzen™ 5 PRO 2400G with Radeon™ Vega 11 Graphics](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-5-pro-2400g#product-specs) isn't considered an APU.

> As per a random Reddit discussion I found this: Basic rule: If it's followed by a G (G, GE, GX...), it has an integrated GPU, if it's not, it doesn't.

This rule is only valid for AMD's desktop processors.  It does not apply to mobile processors or AMD's APUs